# Как сменить кодировку в ISPManager 4?

Tags: ispmanager

Сайт http://www.market-svt.com.ua, на сайте периодически наблюдается [ошибка с кодировкой](http://joxi.ru/n2YbKjnHoVGO4A)

[и еще одна](http://joxi.ru/n2YbKjnHoVG64A)

Сайт стоит на ISP Manager 4, по дефолту кодировка windows-1251. Подскажите пожалуйста, как и что необходимо сделать, чтобы заставить работать сайт на UTF-8?

Comment: во вкладке домены, где то в параметрах домена там это указывается

Comment: Так и сделал - http://joxi.ru/gmvnJK3CLBygNm

Comment: Тем не менее, кодировка осталась прежней http://joxi.ru/L21QnVvu8VGoe2

Comment: так это дело не в панели, это сам сайт через мета тег отдает такую кодировку, смотрите это в верстке сайта

Comment: Попробую, спасибо.